# Django pages accessible through passphrases

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

(Reposted as my first post was worded incorrectly)

Hi,

I have a Django website up which currently supports login authentication and posts, however, I want to make a second-layer of authentication.

I want to know if there is a way that seperate from user authentication, I could have passcode protected pages. For example, a post could be generated on a hidden page, the only way this page is accessible is if a logged in user enters a passcode into a form.

So the user would log in, go to /passform and be greeted by a text input field, once they enter a code which correlates to a post ( for example post1 has a secret passcode of "abc123" ) if the code matches a post it would re-direct them to said page, and, if the code does not correlate it would just error out.

Is there a way to do this within Django or should I be using queries for this?

( for this example I'm also assuming my create post has a function to enter a passphrase in the same way you would enter a title ect so it would be stored in the same database. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way of accomplishing this (just a proof of concept, not production quality code):

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get("password") == "s3cr3t":
            return render(request, "secret_page.html")
    return render(request, "password_page.html")
```

**password_page.html:**

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! thank you very much for your help, I've been scratching my head over this for hours.